# Saving the wrong value on my DB at the column of image through my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm receiving this value at the column img on my DB:
'C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\php2A8D.tmp'

And my public function store are this way:

```
public function store(HeadquarterRequest $request)
{
    $request->validated();

    if ($request->file('img') !== null) {
        // ALTERANDO O NOME DA IMAGEM
        $newName = $request->name .'.'. $request->img->extension();
        // REDIMENSIONANDO A IMAGEM
        $manager = new ImageManager(Driver::class);
        $image = $manager->read($request->file('img'));
        $image->resize(800, 600);
        $path = public_path('img/headquarters/' . $newName);
        $image->save($path);
        $request->merge(['img' => $newName]);
        //dd($request);

    }

    // Salvando os dados no banco de dados
    Headquarter::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('headquarters.index')->with('success', 'Unidade da CO2 Peças criada com sucesso!');
}
```

Why isn't save the name on DB like I set?

I already ensure that my form has the enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: I searched for "*laravel ImageManager upload*" and came across a few examples, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332182/i-want-to-resize-a-photo-with-intervention-image, does that help?

Comment: The point is when I try to create the data. Look at the datatable we find the column img with the value C:\Users\pablo\AppData\Local\Temp\php2A8D.tmp, like a temporary path.

Comment: Sorry, I linked to a bad example.  Yes, it is clear you're saving the tmp file to DB.  My guess is it is something to do with resizing the image before it has been fully processed/saved by PHP/Laravel - it is still a tmp file.  Checking other working examples here on SO might help - there are many.  Laravel makes [file uploads very easy](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-uploads) - have you tried saving the uploaded file first, then creating a resized version of that saved file?